# can i use my wireless adsl2 router+modem as modem only?

Tags: wireless-router, adsl, adsl-router, dsl-modem, adsl2+

I have tenda w150D wireless router+modem. Its antenna is broken & it doesn't support dd-wrt. Now I wish to buy a router that does support dd-wrt. So can I use this current router+modem as modem only and buy a new dd-wrt supported router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect a cable router to the LAN port of this one, you should be able to set it up as it's own network. **You'll want to set up DMZ on the first router to point all traffic to the second one**, and disable it's WiFi if you won't use it.

As an example, I have a router in my room connected to the main router downstairs, and it allows me a fast internet connection without having to use WiFi.

The problem you may have is if the networks are configured to use the same subnets you might find that you can't access the settings / LAN on the second router. Have a look [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5990778_calculate-two-subnets-conflict.html) if you're not sure what this means.

Comment: you mean to say that I can use my adsl modem router as a modem only. for example, in this picture here, I can replace black modem with my modem router? [Picture](http://tinyurl.com/pangtq9)

Comment: Yes. The best way to do so will be to disable all firewall on the first router and use the one on the second. Turning on DMZ will mean that all traffic that comes in to the first router through ADSL will get sent straight to the second router.

Comment: Sorry for asking again & again. I am right now trying to setup DMZ & its asking me to "enter the IP address of the PC that is set as DMZ HOST into DMZ Host IP." Is my router a DMZ host, or is it the PC as it is mentioned above? What IP address should I input here, and how do I find it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I was in Nepal. However if you haven't done it by now it should be the router.